# Cordova 5: making changes only to android platform

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a Cordova 5.0 project and would like to make some CSS and HTML changes that take affect only on Android.

I've tried to make changes to items in the /www_assets but as soon as I run the command $cordova --HDPI --nobuild the files get updated back to the files contained in the root /www folder.

What should be the right process?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your android-specific files in `{project}/merges/android` - see the [Cordova documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli/#merges) for details.

Comment: Thanks Dave. For some reason I don't have the /merges folder under my project root. Is it OK  if I just create it myself?

Comment: Yep, just create the folder and cordova will pick it up